# AWS SDK v2 for s3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4.2, aws-sdk

Can any one provide me a good documentation for uploading files to S3 using asw-sdk Version 2. I checked out the main doc and in v1 we used to do like

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
obj = s3.buckets['my-bucket']
```

Now in v2 when I try as

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
```

am ending up with

```
Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError: missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Here is the documentation : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html, You should find everything that you'd need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per official [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/#Configuration):

> To use the Ruby SDK, you must configure a region and credentials.

Therefore,

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:'us-west-2')
```

Alternatively, a default region can be loaded from one of the following locations:

```
Aws.config[:region]
ENV['AWS_REGION']
```

Comment: My problem here is accessing buckets. Previously we have a method to access it `s3.buckets['my-bucket']`. It looks like changed in version2.

Comment: it should be `s3.bucket['my-bucket']`

Comment: Yeah i tried that as well but ending up with no method error.
`5] pry(main)> s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:'us-west-2')
=> #<Aws::S3::Client>

[8] pry(main)> s3.bucket[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']]
NoMethodError: undefined method `bucket' for #<Aws::S3::Client>`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete S3 demo on aws v2 gem that worked for me:

```
Aws.config.update(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
    Figaro.env.s3_access_key_id,
    Figaro.env.s3_secret_access_key
  )
)
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = s3.list_buckets
puts resp.buckets.map(&:name)
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/09038e1794a76babea02)

[Official list of AWS region IDs here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

If you're unsure of the region, the best guess would be US Standard, which has the ID `us-east-1` for config purposes, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using a `aws.yml` file for your credentials in Rails, you might want to create a file `config/initializers/aws.rb` with the following content:

```
filename = File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "aws.yml"))
config = YAML.load_file(filename)
aws_config = config[Rails.env.to_s].symbolize_keys

Aws.config.update({
                  region: aws_config[:region],
                  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(aws_config[:access_key_id], aws_config[:secret_access_key])
              })
```

The `config/aws.yml` file would need to be adapter to include the region.

```
development: &development
  region: 'your region'
  access_key_id: 'your access key'
  secret_access_key: 'your secret access key'
production:
  <<: *development
```